# Including a header on every asp.net response

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net webforms, is it possible to specify an http header that should go on every response  sent (except for things like images, etc)? I am trying to implement a CSRF token scheme that will send a random token on a per session basis in some http meta tag, if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Http handlers in order to customize your header

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Exactly but i found link with mix http handlers and http module